# Multiple Indicators-With Different Overlay

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

When i have EMA and relative strength [RS] both to plot on the same chart, how do i provide different overlay.
For eg:
EMA will be plotted on price with overlay=true
RS will be plotted on price with overlay=false.
I want it to be displayed like RSI, Can anyone suggest how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this indicator to the separate pane or just edit pine code and change `overlay = true` to `overlay = false`

[image]